# flat one-line json to pandas datafame

Tags: json, pandas

trying to read a very simple and flat json into pandas dataframe. This one is an example, real one has more than 200 variables.

```
    {"ranking":"11.1","real_name":"Robert","aggregate":"3","thirdparty":"none", "notes":""}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("data.json", typ='series')
```

I get:

```
ranking         11.1
real_name     Robert
aggregate          3
thirdparty      none
notes               
dtype: object
```

tried to coerce to dataframe as I need it for further processing with pandas:

```
pd.DataFrame(df)


0
ranking 11.1
real_name   Robert
aggregate   3
thirdparty  none
notes
```

but expected dataframe should be:

```
ranking   real_name   aggregate   thirdparty    notes
11.1       Robert      3           none
```

What step I am missing here to get a tabular dataframe even with only one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.json_normalize`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('data.json') as fp:
    d = json.load(fp)
    df = pd.json_normalize(d)
```

Output

```
>>> df
  ranking real_name aggregate thirdparty notes
0    11.1    Robert         3       none
```

Comment: there is no alternative to avoid using json package?

Comment: Try: `pd.read_json("data.json", typ='series').to_frame().T`